# Not able to catch org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException on timeout

Tags: jenkins, automation, jenkins-pipeline, timeout, mocha.js

When using the declarative pipeline on Jenkins a timeout block should abort the entire job according to the jenkins pipeline documentation. It seems that in my case, the timeout is happening during a shell script that is running a suite of mocha tests, and mocha translates the SIGTERM into a test error. When the error gets back to the jenkinsfile, the `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException` error is no longer catchable, and the job does not abort.
EDIT: It seems that the cause is mocha's parallel functionality, but not sure how to handle that.

Here is the error that mocha (version 9) throws when there is a timeout.

```
1) Uncaught error outside test suite:
     Uncaught Workerpool Worker terminated Unexpectedly
    exitCode: `null`
    signalCode: `SIGTERM`
    workerpool.script: `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jobName/path/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/worker.js`
    spawnArgs: `/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node12.14.0/bin/node,/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jobName/path/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/worker.js`
    spawnfile: `/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node12.14.0/bin/node`
    stdout: `null`
    stderr: `null`

  Error: Workerpool Worker terminated Unexpectedly
      exitCode: `null`
      signalCode: `SIGTERM`
      spawnfile: `/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node12.14.0/bin/node`
      stdout: `null`
      stderr: `null`
  
      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (node_modules/workerpool/src/WorkerHandler.js:292:13)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
```

Below is an example of the jenkisfile being run.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("run-tests") {
                steps {
                    script {
                        try {
                            timeout (60) {
                               sh "npm run mocha-tests"
                               }
                        } catch (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException e) {
                                echo "interrupt ${e.toString()}"
                        } catch (Throwable e) {
                                echo "regular ${e.toString()}"
                        }
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

I would like the job to abort on a timeout. What can I do to ensure it aborts?

Answer (score 0):

I have no mocha project at hand, but it looks like mocha detects the SIGTERM event and errors out, like you said.
That in turn should cause the "sh" step to stop "on-error" instead of being terminated by the timeout.
The timeout wanted to "Abort" the job, but not to cause an error. I guess that is why the "error" state won.

You might try to return the exit code of "sh", by that also prevent it to bail out. You may then check the npm/mocha result afterwards, in case you are interested after a timeout...

```
script {
  try {
    timeout (60) {
      teststate = sh returnStatus: true, script: "npm run mocha-tests"
    }
  } 
  catch (...) {}
}
```